# FCM returning response for single registration id when targeted for multiple registration_ids

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am writing app server side of FCM implementation where it will send a particular message to Multiple devices.

I am using `registration_ids` as key and `JsonArray` with multiple recipients, however the response returned is showing only for one recipient as follows

```
{"multicast_id":7185150746202793615,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

I am not sure whether to set any property in firebase console to enable multiple registration ids acceptance.

**Following is the request json** :

```
{  
   "registration_ids":[  
      [  
         "eU6HKx7QRMc:APA91bEIoJtHmTFz_MzUgbMkoZvwdlXzrMDbCB1via_fV16MRF_Xc0C0KkkVA1diR8QgzRdQtkCy-6JDd5it_NSaiIbIlBDDi0g2GFkmrE4ESMi43dBODBePQrzFLqiKeDmX26DkXB8i",
         "FERTeU6HKx7QRMc:APA91bEIoJtHmTFz_MzUgbMkoZvwdlXzrMDbCB1via_fV16MRF_Xc0C0KkkVA1diR8QgzRdQtkCy-6JDd5it_NSaiIbIlBDDi0g2GFkmrE4ESMi43dBODBePQrzFLqiKeDmX26DkXB8i"
      ]
   ],
   "notification":{  
      "title":"Hello FCM",
      "text":"Notification details"
   },
   "time_to_live":3600,
   "priority":"HIGH"
}
```

**And the response for this request is**

```
{  
   "multicast_id":7697036511101523125,
   "success":0,
   "failure":1,
   "canonical_ids":0,
   "results":[  
      {  
         "error":"InvalidRegistration"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: *the response returned is showing only for one recipient* why do you think that?

Comment: The returned results have only one response(size=1) and total of success and failures is also 1.

Comment: Can you please post your code of sending push notification from server side?

Comment: @Dhruv, I am using Java as server side language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Problem was with this Json formation for request. It has to be

```
{  
       "registration_ids"[ "eU6HKx7QRMc:APA91bEIoJtHmTFz_MzUgbMkoZvwdlXzrMDbCB1via_fV16MRF_Xc0C0KkkVA1diR8QgzRdQtkCy-6JDd5it_NSaiIbIlBDDi0g2GFkmrE4ESMi43dBODBePQrzFLqiKeDmX26DkXB8i",
             "FERTeU6HKx7QRMc:APA91bEIoJtHmTFz_MzUgbMkoZvwdlXzrMDbCB1via_fV16MRF_Xc0C0KkkVA1diR8QgzRdQtkCy-6JDd5it_NSaiIbIlBDDi0g2GFkmrE4ESMi43dBODBePQrzFLqiKeDmX26DkXB8i" ],
       "notification":{  
          "title":"Hello FCM",
          "text":"Notification details"
       },
       "time_to_live":3600,
       "priority":"HIGH"
    }
```

The extra square brackets ([ ]) is causing the issue.